# How to print the content of a variable in python testing within a virtual environment on command line

Tags: python, testing, command-line, python-venv

I have a question pertaining to testing within a virtual environment on command line. I am checking if the following python code:

```
import requests
headers = {"X-Access-Token": "your_api_token"}
url = "https://api.apps.com"
result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

will give the following response:

```
{
  "api_version": "0.0.9",
  "store_name": "Test store",
  "store_url": "test.myshopify.com"
}
```

I'm testing this by typing in the following into my virtual environment on command line (also, just to note, I'm on a preprod server):

```
    (env) SAS@preprod:~$ python
    import requests
    headers = {"X-Access-Token": "abc123"}
    url = "https://api.apps.com"
    result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print result
```

When I type `print result`, however, I get:

```
    <Response [200]>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you expecting to get? Response Code 200 means that the request was succesfull.

Comment: Do you want `print result.json()`? You seem to care about the payload, not just the response.

Comment: To print the html/webpage, try `print result.content`.

Answer (score 1):

`result` is a [Response Object](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response). This object encapsulates the data you wish to print.